# How To Properly Structure php Navigation Bar

Tags: php, navbar, dir

I have a index file in my root directory.

I have a directory called pages.

Nav bar is in the includes directory.

If I want to include the navbar in index.php and also in each one of my pages.php which are located in the pages directory. What is the proper way to structure this nav bar so the php can move up and down directories by what page it is on.

each page is identified as

```
$page = currentPage
```

And here is my current navbar which is in the includes dir

```
<ul>
<?php if ($page == 'home') { ?><li class="active"><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li>
<?php } else { ?><li><a href="../index.php">Home</a><?php } ?>

<?php if ($page == 'contact') { ?><li class="active"><a href="contact.php" class="active">Contact Us</a></li>
<?php } else { ?><li><a href="pages/contact.php">Contact Us</a><?php } ?>

<?php if ($page == 'services') { ?><li class="active"><a href="services.php" class="active">Services</a></li>
<?php } else { ?><li><a href="pages/services.php">Services</a><?php } ?>

<?php if ($page == 'employees') { ?><li class="active"><a href="employees.php" class="active">Employees</a></li>
<?php } else { ?><li><a href="pages/employees.php">Employees</a><?php } ?>

<?php if ($page == 'dashboard') { ?><li class="active"><a href="dashboard.php" class="active">Dashboard</a></li>
<?php } else { ?><li><a href="pages/dashboard.php">Dashboard</a><?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Directory looks like this.

root

root/includes

root/pages

Thanks for your help in advance. I realize I could just do some simple things to get around this but I really want to understand this for the future.

This is how the page is currently laid out:

```
<?php $page = 'contact'; ?>

<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Contact Us</title>
<head>
<base href="http://www.mysite.com/Dir_IM_Working_on_root/pages/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="nav">
<?php include '../includes/nav.php'; ?>
</div><!-- CLOSING NAV DIV -->

<div id="main">

</div><!-- CLOSING MAIN DIV -->

<footer>
<?php include '../includes/footer.php'; ?>
</footer>

</div><!-- CLOSING WRAPPER DIV -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest would be to output absolute URLs in all cases. (/test.php)

If you want to leave the possibility to run your site in a subfolder, you can prepend all paths with a variable. This can be changed to the current position of your site.

Another way is to add a

```
<base href="http://www.example.org/subfolder/" />
```

to your html code and change that accordingly in combination with absolute URLs. All URLs are based on what you put into the attribute. This is a very elegant solution, but it affects a lot, which might be surprising if one is not that trained in web linkage.

I think there is no "right" way. Typo3 uses the base tag variant and it's most likely the way I would use. Lots of other software use the variable variant (or wrap the path in a function -- which is just another way of achieving the same). Just try some ways and decide for the one which seems most appealing to you I'd say.

In my experience the only thing nearly nobody uses are relative URLs.

## Update

Use this html in combination with base html tag.

```
<ul>
<li<?php if ($page == 'home') echo ' class="active' ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li<?php if ($page == 'contact') echo ' class="active' ?>><a href="pages/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
<li<?php if ($page == 'services') echo ' class="active' ?>><a href="pages/services.php">Services</a></li>
<li<?php if ($page == 'employees') echo ' class="active' ?>><a href="pages/employees.php">Employees</a></li>
<li<?php if ($page == 'dashboard') echo ' class="active' ?>><a href="pages/dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have to use absolute URLs. Meaning `/index.php` or `/pages/contact.php` etc.

Comment: Sorry, the trailing slash has to be omitted of course. [Here is a fiddle which depicts two links.](http://jsfiddle.net/DY8vA/) You could place this in any folder, it will always link to the same points.

Comment: How exactly looks your base tag? You have to provide a slash at the end of the value! `<base href="http://www.example.com">` will not work, but `<base href="http://www.example.com/>"` would.

Comment: I think the "pages" is too much in your solution. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DY8vA/1/) where I entered your head without "pages" and the html of my answer. This looks fine to me.

Comment: The "trend" of most frameworks goes into the direction to redirect all calls to a `index.php` file with configuration in `.htaccess`, but this happens only internally and is invisible in the browser. Also this does not fix the issue how to link the pages, which is the reason why Typo3 uses the base tag for help. In my opinion the solution now is very good. If you use multiple separate PHP files or use a htaccess solution to gather all requests in one PHP file is another problem you might decide on.